# Proof that there is no way to have certain profit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Assume there exists the following game/bet. The player gives $x$ amount of money and bets on the result of a football game.

If the player correctly bets that the home team wins, he gets back $a*x$ money.

If he correctly bets that the game ends as a draw, he gets back $b*x$ money.

If he correctly bets that the guest team wins, he gets back $c*x$ money.

I have noticed that when

$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}<1$

then the player can bet $b*c$ money on the home team, $a*c$ on the draw and $a*b$ on the guest and always have profit no matter the outcome. That is because if one does so he gains $abc$ money no matter the outcome and loses $ab+bc+ac$ money. And it can easily be proved that $abc>ab+bc+ac$ if $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}<1$.

My question is:

Why there is $no$ $way$ to bet $x_1$ money on the home team, $x_2$ on draw and $x_3$ on the guest team, so that one always has profit no matter the outcome, when $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}>1$?

This question came up to me by seeing the betting odds for football games and noticing that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$ is always greater than $1$ or else betting companies would go bankrupt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that there exists a betting strategy $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ which makes positive profit no matter what outcome is. Then:

$x_1*a > x_1+x_2+x_3$

$x_2*b > x_1+x_2+x_3$

$x_3*c > x_1+x_2+x_3$

$a > \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{x_1}$

$b > \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{x_2}$

$c > \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{x_3}$

$\frac{1}{a} < \frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2+x_3}$

$\frac{1}{b} < \frac{x_2}{x_1+x_2+x_3}$

$\frac{1}{c} < \frac{x_3}{x_1+x_2+x_3}$

$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} < \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{x_1+x_2+x_3} = 1$